# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast as return of the function call

Tags: c

```
char *doRequest(char *start, char**headers, char *body){}
```

here is my function and I call in this way:

```
char *response ;
response = doRequest(strt_line, headers, body);
```

I get this warning:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

How can I correct this?

Comment: Step 1: you google the error message. Step 2: you find the solution.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your code.  Please show the declaration of `strt_line`, `headers` and `body`.

Comment: If you call `doRequest` without a visible declaration and assign the result to a `char*` object, I'd expect "warning: assignment makes *pointer* from *integer* without a cast", not the other way around. Please double check both your source file and the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is almost certainly that you have failed to declare `doRequest` in a way that it is visible before you attempt to call it. Either add a function prototype (the preferred way) or move its definition above the definition of the function which is calling it.

The wrong way:

```
int main() {
    char *start, *body, **headers;
    doRequest(start, headers, body);
}

char *doRequest(char *start, char**headers, char *body) {
    ...
}
```

The proper way:

```
// Function prototype (argument names unnecessary but useful for ease of reading)
char *doRequest(char *start, char**headers, char *body);

int main() {
    char *start, *body, **headers;
    doRequest(start, headers, body);
}

char *doRequest(char *start, char**headers, char *body) {
    ...
}
```

The reason for this is that when the compiler encounters a function call before it has seen the declaration of the function, it assumes the function's return type is `int`.